# Removing Sublist from ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

For simplicity, let's say I have an `ArrayList` whose indices contain exactly one single-digit integer. For instance:

```
6 4 5 6 0 6 3 4 1 6 1 6 0 6 8 3
```

I would like to filter out all occurrences of the sublist `6 0 6`, such that the new list becomes:

```
6 4 5 3 4 1 6 1 8 3
```

Is there any way of doing this? Using `ListIterator` doesn't seem to work for me, because I have to consider three consecutive elements collectively and I'm honestly not sure how to do that.

Here's a skeleton of the method I have implemented:

```
public static void filterList(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
    ListIterator<Integer> iterator = list.listIterator();
    int elem; 
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        // Remove any sublist of 6 0 6
    }
}
```

**Edit:** Again, for simplicity, let's assume there won't be cases where we have 60606 or similar.

Comment: Why can't use `list.removeAll(sublist)`

Comment: What will be the case if input is 60606 ?

Comment: @Naruto It doesn't matter for this example. I was only trying to illustrate the idea.

Comment: @Sam That would remove all occurrences of `6` or `0`. It wouldn't enforce the ordering of the 3 numbers.

Comment: @4castle ya you are right..but if sublist contains the elements(6 0 6) in order than it would be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an efficient and concise O(nm) solution by using [`Collections.indexOfSubList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#indexOfSubList-java.util.List-java.util.List-):

```
public static void removeAllSubList(List<?> list, List<?> subList) {
    // find first occurrence of the subList in the list, O(nm)
    int i = Collections.indexOfSubList(list, subList);
    // if found
    if (i != -1) {
        // bulk remove, O(m)
        list.subList(i, i + subList.size()).clear();
        // recurse with the rest of the list
        removeAllSubList(list.subList(i, list.size()), subList);
    }
}
```

[Ideone Demo](https://ideone.com/6mobol)

Comment: This sounds like a nicely done solution. Would you mind showing the code for my reference and others'? If it works I will mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: "that this would be an O(n) solution" Really? I just can't wait for you to publish your ground-breaking advances in Computer Science, [many others failed to do it in O(N)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm#Basic_classification).

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi It would be O(n) if it was always searching for `606`, if it was searching for any variable-length sublist, then it would be O(nm), or better if using one of those algorithms you linked to.

Comment: @FieryPhoenix I have updated with code for reference. If you only need to remove `6, 0, 6`, you should make some optimizations.

Comment: I've made my answer completely different after looking at how efficient the solution from @AdrianColomitchi has the potential to be.

Answer (score 3):

[Edited - better, single pass approach]

Custom, enhanced `indexOfSublist` starting the search from `offset`; therefore, we don't restart from `0` each time we removed something (as we did when using `Collections.indexOfSublist` see bottom of this answer).

```
static <T> int indexOfSublist(List<T> haystack, List<T> needle, int offset){
  int toRet=-1;
  int needleLen=needle.size();
  if(needleLen>0) {
    // it makes sense to search
    int haystackLen=haystack.size();
    for(;offset+needleLen<haystackLen && toRet<0; offset++) {
      int compIx;
      for(
          compIx=0; 
          (
                 compIx<needleLen 
              && false==haystack.get(offset+compIx).equals(needle.get(compIx))
          ); 
          compIx++
      );
      if(compIx==needleLen) { // found
        toRet=offset;
      }
    }
  }
  return toRet;
}

public static void filterList(List<Integer> haystack, List<Integer> needle) {
  for(
      int offset=0, ixOfNeedle=indexOfSublist(haystack, needle, offset);
      ixOfNeedle>=0;
      ixOfNeedle=indexOfSublist(haystack, needle, offset)
  ) {
    // found one place. We'll continue searching from here next time
    offset=ixOfNeedle;
    //////////////////////////////////////////
    // for a better removal sequence, see the 
    // 4castle's answer using sublists 
    for(int i=needle.size(); i>0; i--) {
      haystack.remove(ixOfNeedle);
    }
  }
}
```

---

[Collections.indexOfSublist](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#indexOfSubList%28java.util.List,%20java.util.List%29) is what you are after.

```
public static void filterList(ArrayList<Integer> haystack, List<Integer> needle) {
    for(
       int ixOfNeedle=Collections.indexOfSublist(haystack, needle);
       ixOfNeedle>=0;
       ixOfNeedle=Collections.indexOfSublist(haystack, needle)
    ) {
      for(int i=needle.size(); i>0; i--) {
        haystack.remove(ixOfNeedle);
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: While easy to read, this will be very inefficient in larger lists O(mn^2). You should optimize it by using [`List#subList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList(int,%20int)).

Comment: @4castle - how about this? O(n*m/2) on the average case - assuming random len matches in haystack with substrings of needle.

Comment: I spoke a bit too soon when I said we didn't have a method that could start at a certain index. Using `List#subList` was how I intended to be able to improve it, since you can specify a new starting index just by narrowing the list you give it.

Comment: There's no need to write a custom implementation of `indexOfSubList`, when you can already use `subList` of the first parameter to specify a starting index.

Answer (score 2):

```
    //if
    List<String> originalList = new ArrayList<>();
    originalList.add("A");
    originalList.add("B");
    originalList.add("C");
    originalList.add("D");
    //and
    List<String> subList = new ArrayList<>();
    subList.add("A");
    subList.add("C");
    //then
    originalList = originalList.stream().filter(x -> !subList.contains(x)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    
    //originalList should now contain {"B","D"}
```

Answer (score 1):

What I would recommend is to search your `ArrayList` before you make it into a `ListIterator`.

```
public static void filterList(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
    bool firstInstance = false; //Saying we having found our first instance of our sub list
    for(int i=0;i<list.size();++i) {
       if(list.get(i) == 6) //Checks to see if our first index is a 6 or it pointless to check the next two numbers i.e. wasting resources
         if(list.get(i+1) == 0 && list.get(i+2) == 6 && !firstInstance) { //Make sure it a 6 0 6 list
           list.remove(i); //Removes first one
           list.remove(i); //Removes second one which now became our current index number
           list.remove(i); //Removes third one which now became our current index number
         } else
             firstInstance = true; //Our first instances has been found and will now remove duplicate ones!
    }
    ListIterator<Integer> iterator = list.listIterator();
    int elem; 
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        // Remove any sublist of 6 0 6-- Already Done
    }
}
```

Comment: `list.remove(i); list.remove(i+1); list.remove(i+2);` -> `list.remove(i); list.remove(i); list.remove(i);`

Comment: Thank you, it too late for this. I'll make that adjustment right away.

Answer (score 0):

You can use array and list combination for this as find below solution, hope it will help you.

```
    public void testData()
    {
        int tempArray[] = {6, 4, 5, 6, 0, 6, 3, 4, 1, 6, 1, 6, 0, 6, 8, 3};
        List<Integer> resultArray = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i = 0; i < tempArray.length; i++)
        {
            if(tempArray[i] == 6 && tempArray[i+1] == 0 && tempArray[i + 2] == 6) 
            {
                i += 2;
            }
            else
            {
                resultArray.add(tempArray[i]);
            }
        }

        for(int tempInt : resultArray)
        {
            System.out.print("\t" + tempInt);
        }
    }
```

**Note:** You can pass array from your side or return result as per your requirement in above function.